# Conditionally replace value based on multiple other variables

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I want to replace `country_production` in the data df based on the `climate` and `month` values. ie. if `country_production` is `ASIA` & `climate` contains `"tropical"`(Note: may be `tropical1` or `tropical2`), then replace whatever in `country_production` (in this case `"ASIA"`) with `"Thailand"`.

```
   fruit  price climate   quantity   month   country_production
 1 APPLE   20   temperate   100       Jan          USA
 2 ORANGE  10   tropical1   1000      Apr          Brazil    
 3 APPLE   20   temperate   200       Jan          USA
 4 APPLE   20   temperate   300       May          Japan
 5 MANGO    5   tropical1    20       Jul          ASIA
 6 MANGO    5   tropical2    50       Dec          ASIA
```

I used the following code. It worked on mtcars but not on my data.

```
df %>%
     mutate(country_production=replace(country_production, country_production=="ASIA" & climate=="tropical1", "Thailand")) %>%
     as.data.frame()
```

When I test `"Thailand" %in% df$country_production` after running the code, r returns `FALSE`. I am wondering what went wrong.

In summary, 1) I would like to replace a value based on other values; 2) I want to know how to express that some value contains certain characters eg. "tropical"(Note: may be tropical1 or tropical2).

Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `climate` contains "tropical" instead of doing an exact match using `==` use `grepl` to match the pattern. Also make sure the `country_production` column is of class character.

```
df$country_production[grepl("^tropical", df$climate) & 
                      df$country_production == "ASIA"] <- "THAILAND"

df
#   fruit price   climate quantity month country_production
#1  APPLE    20 temperate      100   Jan                USA
#2 ORANGE    10 tropical1     1000   Apr             Brazil
#3  APPLE    20 temperate      200   Jan                USA
#4  APPLE    20 temperate      300   May              Japan
#5  MANGO     5 tropical1       20   Jul           THAILAND
#6  MANGO     5 tropical2       50   Dec           THAILAND
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(fruit = c("APPLE", "ORANGE", "APPLE", "APPLE", 
"MANGO", "MANGO"), price = c(20L, 10L, 20L, 20L, 5L, 5L), climate = c("temperate", 
"tropical1", "temperate", "temperate", "tropical1", "tropical2"
), quantity = c(100L, 1000L, 200L, 300L, 20L, 50L), month = c("Jan", 
"Apr", "Jan", "May", "Jul", "Dec"), country_production = c("USA", 
"Brazil", "USA", "Japan", "ASIA", "ASIA")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: Hi Ronak, thank you for the answer. However, it seems nothing changes after applying the code.

Comment: @Harper Do you have rows which have values with `"tropical"`  and `country_production` as `"ASIA"` in them ? Can you share `dput(head(df))` ?

Comment: Yes. Sorry I may not be able to provide the data as this example is just an analogy to the actual one. But the relative relationship in the data is correct. In fact, "country_production" is created from str_split_fixed(df2$production, ",", 3) where I then used cbind to join it with the original dataframe.

Comment: @Harper what is the output for `sum(grepl("^tropical", df$climate) & 
                      df$country_production == "ASIA")`  ?

Comment: The result is 0

Comment: @Harper that is where the issue is there is no rows where `climate` has "tropical" and `country_production` is "ASIA", hence nothing changes. Can you check those values again? Is there some spelling mistake or check if it is in upper or lower case as well.

Comment: I've checked that there are rows where climate is "tropical" and country_production is "ASIA". I also tried the code on other combinations of values and nothing changed either

Comment: Are you using the correct dataframe name? Is your dataframe called `df` ? Also try `df$country_production[grepl("^tropical", trimws(df$climate)) & trimws(df$country_production) == "ASIA"] <- "THAILAND"`, see if it changes anything.

Comment: I checked what you said, running `"THAILAND" %in% df$country_production` still returns `FALSE`, maybe it's my data frame.

Answer (score 3):

It could be that there are lagging/leading spaces on the data.  One option is `trimws` and if we want to match both "tropical1" and "tropical2", instead of `==`, use the `%in%` (for multiple fixed string matches)

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(country_production=replace(country_production,
       trimws(country_production)=="ASIA" & 
                trimws(climate) %in% c("tropical1", "tropical2"), 
            "Thailand")) %>%
    as.data.frame()
#.  fruit price   climate quantity month country_production
#1  APPLE    20 temperate      100   Jan                USA
#2 ORANGE    10 tropical1     1000   Apr             Brazil
#3  APPLE    20 temperate      200   Jan                USA
#4  APPLE    20 temperate      300   May              Japan
#5  MANGO     5 tropical1       20   Jul           Thailand
#6  MANGO     5 tropical2       50   Dec           Thailand
```

---

If the value is just a substring, then we can use partial matches with `grepl` or `str_detect`

```
library(stringr)
df %>%
    mutate(country_production=replace(country_production,
       str_detect(country_production, "ASIA") & str_detect(climate, "tropical\\d+"), 
            "Thailand")) %>%
    as.data.frame()
# fruit price   climate quantity month country_production
#1  APPLE    20 temperate      100   Jan                USA
#2 ORANGE    10 tropical1     1000   Apr             Brazil
#3  APPLE    20 temperate      200   Jan                USA
#4  APPLE    20 temperate      300   May              Japan
#5  MANGO     5 tropical1       20   Jul           Thailand
#6  MANGO     5 tropical2       50   Dec           Thailand
```

---

As `grepl` is already mentioned here, a `base R` option is

```
df$country_production[with(df, grepl("tropical\\d+", climate) & 
                  grepl("ASIA", country_production))] <- "Thailand"
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(fruit = c("APPLE", "ORANGE", "APPLE", "APPLE", 
"MANGO", "MANGO"), price = c(20L, 10L, 20L, 20L, 5L, 5L), climate = c("temperate", 
"tropical1", "temperate", "temperate", "tropical1", "tropical2"
), quantity = c(100L, 1000L, 200L, 300L, 20L, 50L), month = c("Jan", 
"Apr", "Jan", "May", "Jul", "Dec"), country_production = c("USA", 
"Brazil", "USA", "Japan", "ASIA", "ASIA")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: Hi akrun, do you know what happened if nothing changed after applying the code to me dataset? The dataset is merged from 2 Excel files. Thank you